# Select text values instead of ID's Inner Joining another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables right now that I'm trying to inner join to get some text values. I have a field where I save data. Users are able to select data form comboboxes/textboxes and then it saves - but the values I save from comboboxes are ID's rather than text values. Now I'm trying to join the tables and grab the text values instead of ID's to be displayed in a datagridview.

Here's what my tables look like

```
tbl1
OrigValue             NewValue             FieldName
12                     13                   Dept
17                     18                   Position
9                      10                   Cost
Samm                   Sammy                Name

tblDefinitions
ID            Name                Field 
9             Microsoft           Seller
10            Adobe               Seller
12            Finance             Dept
13            Research            Dept
17            Manager             Position
18            Entry               Position
```

I'm trying to....

```
Select * from tbl1 and inner Join tblDefitions to get text values
```

The problem is that if you look at the 3rd record in tbl1 it shows 9 and 10 which can be referenced in tblDefinitions but the field name is not in tblDefinitions. I'm trying to only JOIN the two tables where the field names match, and display everything else as is.

Desired end result....

```
OrigValue         NewValue       FieldName
Finance           Resarch        Dept
Manager           Entry          Position
9                 10             Cost
```

Comment: 9 and 10 both appear in your second table, why would that third row display as you provided in your example? I would also ask why you are including non existent FK's in your table?

Comment: Because the fieldName is not in tblDefinitions. I'm only trying to get TEXT (Name) values for FieldNames that are in tblDefinition. If there is no match for FieldNames, then display value as is. Cost is a textbox value which does not get saved with ID as comboboxes do and needs to be displayed as such. For everything else (Dept, Position) I don't want to show a number since it has a corresponding text value.

Comment: is fieldname the new value or the old value?

Comment: @takarii so what happens is tbl1 is where I insert all the changes. So a user might initially save Dept = 12. then they change the record and change it to Dept=13 (as shown in 1st record tbl1). I record the changes in this table. But now I'm trying to actually show what the original value was and what the new value is - so user can see what the change was.

Comment: Inner joins will translate things properly, but if the key has nothing to reference to (either as something that exists, or doesnt) a join won't display the id. Your program shouldn't even allow a non existing key to be added into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to join the tblDefinitions twice. Outer join, as there may be missing matches. Then use `COALESCE`to either display the found value or the default.

```
select 
  coalesce(ov.name, cast(t1.origvalue as varchar)) as origvalue,
  coalesce(nv.name, cast(t1.newvalue as varchar)) as newvalue,
  t1.fieldname
from tbl1 t1
left join tbldefinitions ov on t1.origvalue = ov.id and t1.fieldname = ov.field
left join tbldefinitions nv on t1.newvalue = nv.id and t1.fieldname = nv.field;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an error - it get's stuck on a text value and shows this error.....Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JohnSmith' to data type int. This is a value in my OldValue column

Comment: So what's happening is my orig/new value might have text values and I guess when we do the leftjoin and try to t1.origvalue=ov.id - it's trying to convert the origvalue to integer

Comment: Looks like a bad table design then. You can still convert: `on t1.origvalue = cast(ov.id as varchar)` and `on t1.newvalue = cast(nv.id as varchar)`, so that the opposite conversion (`t1.origvalue` and `t1.newvalue` to number) are no longer necessary, because you are telling the DBMS to compare strings instead.

Comment: is there maybe some way to do this that I specify that if fieldname is 'dept' or 'position' then do inner join on ID else don't do inner join

Comment: No, I don't think so, because even when you try to tell the DBMS to check the fieldname first and then look at the orig/newvalue, it may do just the opposite. With SQL you tell the DBMS what to do, but not how to do it. Your best bet would be another database design, but with the design given, my suggestion to convert the IDs to varchar should also work.

Comment: In what case? Have you replaced `id` with `cast(ov.id as varchar)` in the `ON` clauses? And it still doesn't work? What new error are you getting?

Comment: actually this works on that I did cast(ov.id as varchar)

Comment: Hey i hope you can help me, what if say I want to join another table - say the OrigValue and NewValue are not in theDefinitions - is there a way for me to link it to tblUsers for example just on the ID's - in this case I don't need the fldname. Basically I have more values (ID's) that need to get linked to other tables and just trying to build them into this one query. Or do i need a UNION or something

Comment: A `UNION ALL` would be the most readable I guess. But you could just as well outer join all tables potentially needed `left join tblusers u on  on t1.origvalue = cast(u.id as varchar) and t1.fieldname = 'User'. In your select clause you can use `CASE` as in `case when t1.fieldname = 'User' then coalesce(u.name, cast(t1.origvalue as varchar)) else coalesce(ov.name, cast(t1.origvalue as varchar))  end as origvalue`. But as mentioned, a `UNION ALL` query would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will match up your keys such that it shows you what the original `Name` was, and the new one.

```
SELECT tblDefinitions.Name AS 'Original Value', t.Name AS 'New Value', FieldName
FROM tbl1 
JOIN tblDefinitions ON tbl1.OrigValue = tblDefinitions.ID 
JOIN tblDefinitions t ON tbl1.NewValue = t.ID
```

However, I don't understand the relation between `FieldName` in tbl1 and `Field` in tblDefinitions.

Comment: When I populate my comboboxes I use the ID and Name from tblDefinitions. When user selects it and saves it - I save the ID. Later on if user changes value, I save the original and new value in tbl1. Field/FieldName will match in most cases, however in some cases if there is no match tbl1.field = and tblDefinitions.FieldName then I want to display data as is basically. Only show text values for FieldName that have a match in tbl1.FIELD

Comment: @Bobski I would probably try to avoid that situation happening in the first place. Numbers tell users absolutely nothing without reference points - so if displaying your desired result in a datagrid your user wouldnt know anything. Perhaps it would be wise to review your application and introduce code that stops this from being a scenario?

Comment: That's why I'm trying to display the FieldName so if they use FieldName = Cost and it shows Original Value = 9 and New Value = 10 then they will know that the cost has changed. VS Dept, or Position - a number does not tell them anything

Comment: so if im understanding correctly- if fieldname is cost, the old value/new value is a change to _cost_ specifically, eg £10 to £9 and has nothing to do with the ID's in the definition table, but if it was Dept, then the values relate to the`Name` field in the definitions table?

Comment: Yes that is correct. But in some cases....in this case COST value if JOINED with tblDefinitions might pull a value that's why I was trying to find a way to JOIN the two tables together on ID and FieldName so that only those values display 'Name' and leave all the other fields where fieldname is not FIELD as they are

Answer (score 0):

You not joining 'tblDefinitions' twice with both new and old value with id column to get its text value.

```
select 
        isnull(tdo.Name,cast(t1.OrigValue as varchar)) OrigValue         
       ,isnull(tdn.Name,cast(t1.NewValue as varchar)) NewValue
       ,t1.FieldName 
 from
    tbl1 t1
    left join tblDefinitions tdo on  t1.FieldName = tdo.Field and t1.OrigValue = tdo.ID
    left join tblDefinitions tdn on t1.FieldName = tdn.Field and t1.NewValue = tdn.Id
```

Comment: when you do left join on t1.origValue=tdo.ID this throws an error because some origValues are text

Comment: Inner join will throw error.. try this it is workiing

Comment: yes it is working ....my apologies. I have one more question. I have more values in tbl1 that need to be linked to another table - say tbl1 but I only need to link it with ID - no need to use fldname. How would I do that? Could you possibly give me an example?